# GridView and XMLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I want to display xml content at aspx page. There is my aspx code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvXML" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        DataSourceID="xmlData">
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="xmlData"
        DataFile="Items.xml">
    </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

And there is XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<inventories>
    <vehicle name="lanos" year="1984" instock="no">
        <rate>ok</rate>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle name="jeep" year="2013" instock="yes">
        <rate>dziadowstwo</rate>
    </vehicle>
</inventories>
```

What do I wrong, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should assist you. It appears you are missing the XPath. You can see further documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.xpath.aspx).

In short it might be as such.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="xmlData"
    DataFile="Items.xml"
    XPath="//vehicle">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

EDIT: although I know gridview is a nice pre-wired control you may also find it more beneficial to dig into a generic repeater and use item templates. in my web forms days it always seemed like there was something I needed to do that became overly messy with gv. However that is just an fyi for u down the road.

Comment: try it now I forget the "//" in the path sorry.

Comment: In my experience, the repeater is much more useful control than GridView

Comment: sorry about that its been a while since I used those controls. seriously though dig into XPath heavy. There are a lot of cool things you can do there.

Comment: agrees with jugg1es by miles +1